# Im getting an error trying to decode my json api data into a codable class

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am getting an error **Cannot convert value of type 'Any' to expected argument type 'Data'** when trying to decode my json api data obtained from alamofire

```
var events = [Events]()

let URL_GET_DATA = "http://192.168.100.3/PrototypeWebService/api/getevents.php"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        Alamofire.request(URL_GET_DATA).responseJSON{ response in
            if let json = response.result.value{
                print(json)
                do {
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    let eventObject = try decoder.decode(Events.self, from: json)
                    print(eventObject)


                    self.EventTable.reloadData()

                } catch {
        }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `responseData` method instead of `responseJSON`

```
Alamofire.request(URL_GET_DATA)
.responseString { json in 
    print(json)
}
.responseData { response in
    do {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let eventObject = try decoder.decode([Events].self, from: response)
        print(eventObject)
        self.EventTable.reloadData()
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Comment: It prints **Evny.Events** as output

Comment: It doesn't print an array of objects

Comment: @Carl Check the updated answer. Update your question with json response you get from `print(json)`

Answer (score 0):

First of all it's highly recommended to handle **all** errors, at least print them out.

If you want to deal with the raw data of the Alamofire response use `responseData` rather than `responseJSON`

I guess `events` is supposed to be an array

```
var events = [Events]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    Alamofire.request(URL_GET_DATA).responseData { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let data):
           do {
               let decoder = JSONDecoder()
               events = try decoder.decode([Events].self, from: data)
               print(events)
               self.EventTable.reloadData()
           } catch { 
               print(error) 
           }
        case .failure(let error): 
             print(error)
        }
   }
}
```

Note:

As already mentioned in one of your previous questions structs and classes which are used as items in an array should be named in singular form. Semantically each item in the array represents **one** `Event`.

Comment: I am getting this error: **typeMismatch(Swift.Array<Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))**

Comment: Then it's a dictionary. I suspect there is a root object you are ignoring. Please edit the question and add the JSON, at least the beginning.